# Insert value into the table in sqldatabase

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

Hello, following is the code, i tried to insert data into a database but i'm unable to insert into the table.

```
-(BOOL) saveData:(NSString *)registerNumber name:(NSString *)name department:(NSString *)department year:(NSString *)year
{
    const char *dbpath=[databasePath UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSString *insertSQL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into studentsDetail (regno,name,department,year)values(\"%d\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",[registerNumber integerValue],name,department,year];
        const char *insert_stmt=[insertSQL UTF8String];


        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement,  NULL);
        if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            return YES;

        }
        else
        {
            return NO;
        }
        sqlite3_reset(statement);
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: try to get sqlite error code/description using sqlite3_errmsg(_dbHandle)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding those values to an NSString. Try using sqlite3_bind. It may work.

```
const char *sql = "INSERT INTO studentsDetail (regno,name,department,year) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(cruddb, sql, 1, &statement, NULL)) {
   sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, [registerNumber integerValue]);
   sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [department UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 4, [year UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   sqlite3_step(statement);
   sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try single quotes in -

```
 NSString *insertSQL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into studentsDetail (regno,name,department,year)values(\'%d\',\'%@\',\'%@\',\'%@\')",[registerNumber integerValue],name,department,year];
```

This worked for me in a similar case. You can use sqlite3_Bind_Blob datatype as it will store the data as it is.